# Raspberry Pi with Logitech C170

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to connect a webcam Logitech C170 to the Raspberry Pi board and use the raspistill command. But somehow it does not work. I'm getting the following error.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/mjpg-streamer-code-182/mjpg-streamer $ raspistill -w 640 -h 480 -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th 0:0:0 &
[1] 2390
pi@raspberrypi ~/mjpg-streamer-code-182/mjpg-streamer $ mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)          
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

I've tried updating rpi, updating and upgrading apt-get, also enabled the camera option in raspi-config. Nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: raspistill by default works with rpi-camera module and doesn't capture images for USB cameras by default.

You will need to change a config file as per mentioned in this link. 

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=61678&p=459027

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raspistill command is primarily used for the Raspberry Pi Camera Module. For webcams, use fswebcam - https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/ is a useful reference. Are you trying to use MJPG-Streamer? If so then raspistill will not help - it will only capture a still image and save it to the Pi. Use the mjpg-streamer command - see http://www.justrobots.net/?p=97 for more details.